# What do you call it when someone points with their eyes?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

If two people make eye contact and someone points at something (without speaking) with only their eyes, what is that called?

Comment: It's pointing. One can point with any part of the body, or extensions of it. Different cultures have different pointing habits -- some point with the lip, for instance, instead of the hand. Terry Pratchett poked fun at this ethnocentrism when he named a mountain in a foreign country "Mt. Yourfingeryoufool", because that was what people said when he asked what its name was.

Comment: Also maybe _indicate_

Answer (score 6):

Usually we say that the person who is "pointing" with his/her eyes is *signaling* in that direction (with his/her eyes). For example, "He signaled with his eyes that there were guards standing in the corner".

Other phrases that you could use are, for example:
**1.** He *indicated* that ...
**2.** He *gazed* to the left to show that ...

Feel free to use any other synonyms that are similar to "signal" or "indicate".

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to confirm. So basically, point/signal/indicate and synonyms and we use "with eyes". So there's no alternative singular term, which will take out "with eyes" from the equation, right?

Answer (score 2):

You might also *dart a glance at* someone or something, meaning that you would look at the subject for a very short time ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dart_1)).

Comment: Or even just *glance* without the qualification.

Comment: Glance, gaze, and stare are all actions of the eyes without using “eyes.”

Answer (score 1):

Is eye-pointing a complete fallacy? I don't believe it exists as a verb only but don't see why it shouldn't :)

Actually, I've just done a search and found this text:

> Eye-pointing is described as "The context-relevant, controlled and intentional use of gaze in order to direct one or more partner's visual attention to any item or object for a deliberate communicative purpose. — [About the Eye Pointing Classification Scale - UCL](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/gaze/eye-pointing-classification/epcs-about)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just deleted my previous comment. Sorry, I was going through the review queue and confused your answer with a question because it starts with one. Welcome to ELU, anyhow. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

While you would need a verb (shot, threw, gave, etc.) to supplement this, the glance itself is called a **pointed glance**:

> She shot a pointed glance diagonally toward the kitchen, loath to speak and wake Faith. ... He must have caught the meaning in her glance, because his expression lightened. — [Bearly a Chance](https://books.google.com/books?id=heaoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22pointed%20glance%22%20meaning&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiepa3H0tf3AhULjokEHZmjDh04ChDoAXoECAIQAw)

Simply glancing at something can be ambiguous. For example, if you're "darting a glance at" the clock, that signals that you're impatient and fails to have any connotation that you're trying to tell someone else to look at the clock too.

Note that giving *someone* a pointed glance usually means that you're trying to communicate something *to* them with your expression (not something *about* them per se).